# Every Functional on V has the form T(x) = <x,y> for a unique y in V?

Tags: linear-algebra

Every functional on V has the form T(x) =  for some unique vector y in v?
V is a finite-dimensional space.

The book says it's false, but it is the book that is wrong.
The end.

Comment: What kind of space is $V$? Just a hilbert space?

Comment: Finite dimensional

Comment: I think it's true if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, isn't it?

Comment: Because if it is finite-dimensional it always has an Inner product?

Comment: Note the following applies if you're working in a hilbert space (complete vector space with an inner product). If $T$ is a continuous linear operator then this is definitely true. And I think in finite dimensions every linear operator is continuous so this is true. I'm unsure why your book is saying this is false.

Comment: for a unique $y$ IN $V$ it should say, by the way what you have is a functional, not an operator.

Comment: However, if your space is infinite-dimensional, this can fail.  For instance, consider the space of smooth and square-integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, with the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$.  Then $T[f]=f(0)$ is a linear functional, but it's not equal to the inner product with any element of the vector space.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume $V$ is a finite-dimensional real inner-product space. Put $n=\dim V$ and recall that $\dim V^*=n$.

Now, let 
$$
W=\{\langle-,v\rangle\in V^*:v\in V\}
$$
and note that $W$ is a subspace of $V^*$. Define $T:V\to W$ by $T(v)=\langle-,v\rangle$ and note that $T$ is linear.

We claim that $T$ is injective. To prove this, let $v\in\ker T$ so $T(v)(x)=0$ for all $x\in V$. It follows that $\langle x,v\rangle=0$ for all $x\in V$. In particular, $\langle v,v\rangle=0$. Hence $v=\mathbf 0$ so $T$ is indeed injective.

Finally, the rank-nullity theorem implies 
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\im T+\dim\ker T=\dim V=n
$$
Since $\dim\ker T=0$, it follows that $\dim\im T=n$. That is, $\im T$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of $W$ which in turn is subspace of the $n$-dimensional space $V^*$. Hence $W=V^*$ proving your claim.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, this proves that the statement is true?

Comment: Yes, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional real inner-product space, then this is true. Also, we could replace "real" by "complex" and the statement is still true.